# Hyperledger composer document attachment support

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Does hyperledger composer support document (.doc, PDF, or an image) attachment? Basically, I want to add a document as a property of an asset in the model file. I'm a beginner,  any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable not to put huge files into the blockchain. Therefore what you can do is store it somewhere and store the link to one path variable. To make sure the file isnot altered, you can hash the contents of the file while storing it somewhere and check the hash while retrieving it. In case you need to store the files in blockchain being mandatory, you can encode files to base64(recommended) string and decode it to get the file again.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your file data into the `IPFS`. IPFS is a protocol and network designed to create a content-addressable, peer-to-peer method of storing and sharing hypermedia in a `distributed file` system.

For IPFS I recommend you to follow the [link](https://ipfs.io/).

IPFS will give you a `Hash` link after successfully upload a file. You can **store** that **hash** into an **asset** or participate of hyperledger composer.

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: using IPFS, as long as anyone has the hash provided from IPFS, they can retrieve the doc from IPFS. I don't want to happen that.  How do I secure the doc from an authorized access?  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you mean a PDF file. And there is a simple Asset called Invoice

```
Asset Invoice identified by id {
  o String id
  o String pdfLocation
  o String pdfHash
}
```

Now you could technically define an array and store the pdf as a string but as mentioned, it is not a good practice. Instead in one of my PoCs I have implemented a solution as follows.

1. First step is a user creates a new `Invoice` asset and along with it wants to attach a pdf copy of the actual invoice
2. He sends an API call with the details and uses `multer` to parse the PDF. This returns the info in `req.file` which is then handled using `express` and stored in `mongoDB`
3. Once the file has been stored in `mongoDB`, it can only be accessed by a direct API call to the server. Whatever ACL you want to apply, you do it here in the middleware
4. Once the document is stored, `mongoDB` or any other db will return a primary key. This is stored in `pdfLocation`. When the invoice wants to be retrieved, the user will first get the `Invoice` asset, access the `pdfLocation` and then query the document from mongoDB itself by referencing the primary key

Quick snippets to get you started

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const router = express.Router();
let storage = multer.memoryStorage();
let upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.post('/invoice, upload.single('invoice-pdf'), createInvoice);

const createInvoice = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Do your usual stuff of connecting via businessNetworkConnection
  // Assume the file upload is a success

  let document = new documentSchema({
        originalName: req.file.originalname,
        file: req.file.buffer,
        creationDate: new Date()
       );
  let param = await document.save();
  primarykey = param._id;

  let newInvoice = factory.newResource(BASE_NS, 'Invoice', req.body.id);
  // Add whatever values you want
  newInvoice.pdfLocation = primaryKey;
  await registry.add(newInvoice);
}
```

Document schema is a simple collection to store the info. Looks like this

```
const documentSchema = new Schema({
  originalName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  file: {
    type: Buffer,
    required: true
  },
  creationDate: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
});
```

Assume you can do something similar if you use a different database
Now the user wants to retrieve the same PDF file from the invoice. End result, he calls an API from the frontend and is given a PDF he can download

```
router.get('/invoice/pdf', someSecretACL, getPdfFile);

const getPdfFile = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Connect to the business network, load the registry

  let invoice = await registry.get(req.body.id) // Get the invoice
  let primaryKey = invoice.pdfLocation;

  // Now get the bytes from mongoDB and send them to the browser
  let array = await documentSchema.find({ _id: id });
  let pdf = array[0] // assume successful call
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.send(pdf .file);
};

const someSecretACL = async (req, res, next) => { // Do some checks here };
```